# how to check iptables status in centos 7.6

Tags: centos, iptables, services

When I check iptables status in `CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)` like this:

```
[miao@MeowK8SSlave4 ~]$ service iptables status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status iptables.service
Unit iptables.service could not be found.
```

how to successfully check status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only interested in determining the current firewall status, it's likely that the `firewalld` `systemd` service is handling that for you in CentOS 7 (unless you changed some defaults in the installation).

To query the status of the service you can do:

```
# systemctl status firewalld
```

To stop the firewall, you can do:

```
# systemctl stop firewalld
```

And to permanently disable it you can do (replace `disable` with `enable` to do the reverse):

```
# systemctl disable firewalld
```

You can also use the `firewall-cmd` command to poke around and find more specific information on the current firewall configuration.
For example, to find out if the firewall is running

```
# firewall-cmd --state
```

The [RedHat firewall docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-using_firewalls) have a nice diagram showing how `iptables` or `firewalld` services are both (but not simultaneously) connected to the `iptables` command.
The docs also have a page describing the [differences between the two](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-setting_and_controlling_ip_sets_using_iptables) and how to configure your system to use the `iptables` service instead of `firewalld`.

Answer (score 1):

`iptables.service` is part of the `iptables-services` package:

```
# yum whatprovides /usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service 
[...]
iptables-services-1.4.21-34.el7.x86_64 : iptables and ip6tables services for iptables
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service
```

However, with just the `iptables` package installed, you can still have an active iptables configuration. You can check that with `iptables --list`.

Comment: how to disable iptables?`[miaoyou@MeowK8SSlave3 ~]$ systemctl stop iptables.service
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to manage system services or units.
Authenticating as: miaoyou
Password:
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
Failed to stop iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not loaded.`

Comment: You need to run `systemctl daemon-reload` after installing iptables-services for systemd to pick up the new unit files.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the iptables service status in CentOS:

```
sudo systemctl status iptables
sudo systemctl status ip6tables
```

if the services are not started yet , you can start them as :

```
sudo systemctl start iptables
sudo systemctl start ip6tables
```

Comment: This is not totally accurate. I just jumped on a CentOS 7 box, and sudo systemctl status iptables returns Unit iptables.service could not be found. While at the same time sudo iptables -L returns a BOATLOAD of rules that are in effect.

Comment: @number9   Question is  "how to check iptables status in centos 7.6"   , and  below  is what I am  getting after `systemctl status iptables`   shell  command :   `  systemctl status iptables
● iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2021-03-12 19:56:09 CET; 11h ago
 Main PID: 13550 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/iptables.service

Mar 12 19:56:09 myserver.com systemd[1]: Starting IPv4 ....`

Comment: @number9 what a  nice  welcome  in my first answer , you are downvoting me. I can not do any thing if your server is misconfigured , the OPs  question was  **how to check iptables status in centos 7.6**  and  this  is  my  working  answer (yes  if  you need  I can take screen shot too) .  It seem  to be I am not welcomed  here..

Comment: @everyt4u There are multiple packages that can alter iptables rules, some of them don't use the iptables service. The Question is a little bit misleading here because it is not clear whether the service was meant or the program `iptables`.

Comment: @everyt4u You were down voted because your solution required a package that OP may not have, but I do in fact know that the iptables command is installed by default on Cent 7.6.

Comment: @MathiasWeidner Thank you Dear Mathias for kindly answering. This is the way I am looking for in an online community, and even you stated question can be misleading , and i wanted add my contribution innocently .But suddenly a problem kid comes and destroys all your willing to continue in your first msg.. Even he is stating **but I do in fact know that the iptables command is installed by default on Cent 7.6**..   Best regards to you and others. sorry been sensible against such people..